# How to fix response issue in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

After adding some data from csv file getting 415 status code in jmeter response. I am getting success in postman for same payload which is present in jmeter sample request header. But in jmeter it's showing error. Error is "{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"|fc0a70d2-46g24ac7bc010330.fc0a10d3_c9c4264_"}". I configured all the things properly. Please guide me how to fix that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't configure at least "one thing" property: [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager). Add it to your Test Plan and set it up to send the same ["Content-Type" header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) as Postman does

Most probably the value should be [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Metadata_and_schema)

Also be aware that if you can successfully execute the request using Postman you can just record the request execution using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, it worked after using of recording

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the problem may persist in "HTTP Request" sampler: ensure the "Use multipart/form-data" is un-ticked.